# websocket secure connection wss://localhost:443/ not making a connection to server

Tags: security, websocket, connection, wss

I have a client server application, but when I try to make a WSS connection, it gives me an error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connect("wss://localhost:8080/WebsocketHttpListenerDemo").Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

public static async Task Connect(string uri)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(6000); //wait for a sec, so server starts and ready to accept connection..

            ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;
            try
            {
                webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None);
                await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
        finally
        {
            if (webSocket != null)
                webSocket.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket closed.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the Help Center about [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details about the types of questions you are allowed to ask. This question, as currently asked, is likely to be closed as off-topic as it lacks any attempt on your part to debug the problem. For instance, what is the actual error, and which line of code I reporting it?

Comment: Your question title says you are trying to connect to `wss://localhost:443/`, but the code you have shown is actually trying to connect to `wss://localhost:8080/` instead.  Does your server accept WSS connections on port 8080? Have you tried connecting to port 443 instead?